# Ubuntu 11.04 and OpenLDAP - where is the config?

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ldap, openldap

I've been asked to setup a multimaster LDAP environment on Ubuntu 11.04 - instead of a single master server. I cloned the master server and recreated it into two VMs. I am trying to follow the instructions on the OpenLDAP documentation here:

http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html

and it talks about modifying the cn=config tree within LDAP. The subdirectory tree appears to be there at:

`/etc/ldap/slapd.d/`

and a

`slapcat -b cn=config`

drops out a load of config information. When I try to connect using a browser and the admin bind credentials:

`ldapsearch -D '<adminDN>' -w <password> -b 'cn=config'`

I get:

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object
```

I don't see the config context when I connect via an LDAP browser either. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't see what it is!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using the wrong admin credentials.

Rather certain Ubuntu is setup to use root over SASL/EXTERNAL Unix Sockets as rootDN by default.

```
# {0}config, config  
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config  
olcRootDN: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth`
```

Try using `sudo ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y external -b cn=config`

Answer (score 1):

Use your old slapd.conf if you have one or copy the one out of /usr/share/doc.
If you've got your slapd.conf you can delete the slapd.d/* data and create a new slapd.d configuration from your slapd.conf with

slapadd -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d -n0

be sure to test your configuration with

slaptest -f slapd.conf

and be sure to own everything in slapd.d to openldap or any special ldap-user.
OpenLDAP does not provide any slapd.conf file in the default installation. You could do everything with ldapmodify in "live"-Mode, but to provide the first-time-configuration you should use a slapd.conf and convert it.

cheers,